# Using an "approximate" STL map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, approximate, approximate-nn-searching

I would like to create an STL map to find whether an item is close enough to another item in 3 dimensional space. So far, my "less-than-functor" has worked quite well, pasted to the following link.

Now this problem isn't quite the "nearest neighbor" problem. Rather it is a problem of "is there a neighbor within some distance."

My example just shows a single dimension. I've skipped the Y/Z dimensions for clarity.

[My attempt so far](http://pastebin.com/dKztPGM2) :

```
class ApproximateLessFunctor {
 public:
  ApproximateLessFunctor( float fudgeFactor ) :
    mFudgeFactor( fudgeFactor ) {};

  bool operator()( float a, float b ) const {
    return (a < (b - mFudgeFactor) );
  }

  float mFudgeFactor;
};

typedef map<float, int, ApproximateLessFunctor> XAxisMap;

class XAxis {
 public:
  XAxisMap vMap;

  XAxis(ApproximateLessFunctor functor, float x, int v)
  : vMap( functor )
  {
    vMap.insert(make_pair(x, v));
  }
};
```

On rare occasions, and I mean- really rare- the maps don't find a matching entry when positions overlap.

Is there something I can do better to implement this, still using STL containers?

Comment: So this is the nearest neighbor problem with a search radius, right? Your might want to have a look at the FLANN library, it implements radius search. I guess other libraries as well.

Comment: Your functor **must** define a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).  Yours doesn't.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I was afraid you'd say that.

Comment: Actually, on a second look, I think it **does** define a SWO, but I don't think the multi-dimensional version will.   Why not post it?

Comment: Done. pasted the 3d version.  http://pastebin.com/dKztPGM2

Comment: @OliCharlesworth His function doesn't define a SWO, since if `b - a < fudge` and `c - b < fudge`, his function may return true for `a, c`, but false for `a, b` and `b, c`.

Comment: So is there another approach I could take, like to use an unordered map? Could I "hash" a value, even if checks for entries are approximate?

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think that's ok, though.  The requirement is that `(a < b) && (b < c) => (a < c)`, but not vice versa.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth There _is_ a requirement that it work both ways.  That `!(a < b) || !(b < c)) => !(a < c)`.  (Think about it for a moment, and I think you'll agree.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I agree that it makes sense intuitively, but I wasn't sure it necessarily followed from the requirements.  But I did think about it, and I now agree!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes.  I've addressed this in the past by defining a comparison function which broke the domain up into finite areas of `mFudgeFactor` (by rounding both elements down to the nearest multiple of `mFudgeFactor`), which results in a legal operator, but I don't think it will help in his case.

Comment: I believe the property @OliCharlesworth et al is discussing is the transitive property of Strict Weak Ordering. However, STL maps also require the comparison to be asymetric, where if a != b and a < b, it is not the case that b < a. In fact, I kind of expected to define an equality functor for the map, but I did not. The equality condition is with the unordered_map, which I am not using for this solution. Do I have my understanding correct?

Comment: @macetw Sort of.  The standard requires that `!(a<b) && !(b<a)` define an equivalence relationship.  Not necessarily anything to do with the operator `!=`, but more or less what one would intuitively understand by "equals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now this problem isn't quite the "nearest neighbor" problem. Rather it is a problem of "is there a neighbor within some distance."

The latter is phrased pretty simply in terms of the former, though. Find the nearest neighbor, then determine if it's close enough. This seems like a reasonable route to go considering the number of data structures available to you for the task.

Namely, a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is extremely common and not too hard to implement. Also relevant is an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), though I haven't implemented that and cannot comment on its difficulty.

Comment: Using a grid of regions will go a long way _IF_ your points are somewhat evenly distributed.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Hm? Neither of those use grids.

Comment: No, I was just thinking of yet another option.  kd-trees are definitely win if points are clumped, but grids might be better for some data.  You have a good answer, I was mostly musing.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh, gotcha. A kd-tree will generate a grid if the points are uniformly distributed. :) (Though you're right, hard-coding for a grid, like an oct-tree, could save space. But the generality of a kd-tree wins to me.)

Comment: This is not an even distribution problem.

Comment: @macetw: That's fine, neither data structure requires it.

Comment: Kudo's to @MooingDuck. The grid of regions is our best approach, where we turn our "fudge factor" into a grid size of maps, no longer with map keys of "float" but keys of "int," where those integers are truncated by: 'int(grid/fudgefactor)'. It's not precise, but it is very close to what we already had. The KD tree approach (using "ANN" or "FLANN" would be the ideal).